# Assign row number to textboxes

Tags: jquery

How can I assign a row number as a value of the textbox?

I have the following.

```
<div id="rows">
    <div><input type="text"></div>
    <div><input type="text"></div>
    <div><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this with `jQuery`?

```
<div id="rows">
    <div><input type="text" value="1"></div>
    <div><input type="text" value="2"></div>
    <div><input type="text" value="3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just be careful with the `input` selector that will select buttons as well is they are inside the rows div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$("#rows input").each(function(i, elem) {
    $(this).val(i+1);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5mfE/)

Comment: You can use `this.value` there is no need to create jQuery object to set the value. and `input` selector will select not only `textboxes` it will select buttons etc' as well.

Comment: He doesn't have anything but textboxes, so why slow the selector down by filtering for only type="text"? Don't over-analyze :P

Comment: That `epsilon` overhead doesn't count. And you can never be sure his HTML is full and not a simplified demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#rows input[type='text']").each(function(index) {
    this.value = index + 1;
});
```

Comment: i dont know why you got neg'd